# Exportar .zip con multiples archivos y cambiar nombre y extensiones (ZipArchive)

Tags: php, zip

Estoy utilizando ZipArchive con PHP para crear un archivo .zip en el que exportar todos los archivos que los usuarios suben a la web.
Dentro de este archivo van muchas carpetas, cada carpeta corresponde a un ID y dentro de cada una puede haber uno o varios archivos (imágenes, .pdfs...)

Se exporta bien y me lo clasifica en carpetas, el problema que tengo es que hay archivos que no tienen extensión y me gustaría que si un archivo no la tiene, se añada. He pensado en mirar el mimetype del archivo y en función de eso que lo añada, pero no sé cómo plantearlo. Aparte, cada archivo se debe renombrar siempre con la secuencia para el nombre: id_de_su_carpeta + 01, id_de_su_carpeta + 02, y así sucesivamente...

¿Cómo puedo modificar mi código para añadir extensión en el caso de que no la tenga y asegurarme que se renombra correctamente?

```
    $zipname = 'nameofzip.zip';
    $local_file = $dir_adjuntos . $zipname;

    if(file_exists($local_file)){
        $overwrite = true;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($local_file, $overwrite ? ZipArchive::OVERWRITE : ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        $filepath = $this->getModel('Archive','ArchivesModel')->getFilenameWithFullPath($file);
        $zip->addFile($filepath, 'nameofzip'.DS.$file->archive_id.DS.$file->filename);
    }

    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($local_file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($local_file);
    die();
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
nameofzip/9201/8728(2).pdf --> debe ser: nameofzip/9201/9201_01.pdf
nameofzip/9202/8799(1)     --> debe ser: nameofzip/9202/9202_01.pdf
nameofzip/9203/8802(1).jpg --> debe ser: nameofzip/9204/9203_01.jpg
nameofzip/9203/8802(2).jpg --> debe ser: nameofzip/9204/9203_02.jpg
nameofzip/9204/8839(1)     --> debe ser: nameofzip/9204/9204_01.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo tienes que buscar la extensión del fichero no es lo mas conveniente utilizar pathinfo ya que tendrías que crear un array que ocupa más espacio. Simplemente busca el "." y si no existe la extensión le agregas el anterior.

Tu código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($local_file, $overwrite ? ZipArchive::OVERWRITE : ZipArchive::CREATE);
//-- En caso de que sea el primero debes tener alguna extensión por defecto
$last_ext = ""; //-- La que creas conveniente
foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
    $filepath = $this->getModel('Archive','ArchivesModel')->getFilenameWithFullPath($file);
    $ext_pos = strrpos($file->filename, '.');
    if ($ext_pos === false) {
        $file->filename = $file->filename.".".$last_ext;
    } else {//-- Agregas la última extensión valida
        $last_ext = substr($file->filename, $pos);
    }
    $zip->addFile($filepath, 'nameofzip'.DS.$file->archive_id.DS.$file->filename);
}

$zip->close();
```